# MySQL replace parent name with parent id

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a Table (t) like this

```
t.Name  t.Parent  t.Id
John    Bob       1
Frank   Bob       2
Alice   Frank     3
Tim     John      4
Lucy    Bob       5
Tim     Frank     6
...
```

Now I want to replace the t.Parent string with the Id of the parent. Is there any way of going about this in MySQL or is the best way to make a little script?

Edit: Thanks All

Comment: Yes in the same table, thanks :)

Comment: -1 Please ask a question, do not just post data here

Comment: @Daric ulvund did ask a question. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Brendan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467385/mysql-replace-parent-name-with-parent-id#answer-6467521) has the shortest solution with the joined update.

Here is a different one with copying the data:

```
CREATE TABLE parents LIKE t;
INSERT INTO parents SELECT * FROM t;
UPDATE t SET parent=(SELECT id FROM parents WHERE name=t.parent ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1);
```

A view could be enough but MySQL refuses to use it in this way.

After the update ran you can modify the type of the `parent` field to the same as `id` has:

```
ALTER TABLE t CHANGE parent parent integer;
```

And of course you can drop the copy table:

```
DROP TABLE parents;
```

Comment: I would protect you in prison

Comment: @ulvund: There is a slight problem with this answer's UPDATE. If field `t.Name` has duplicate names, then the SELECT will yield more than 1 name and will raise error. I guess `t.Name` is UNIQUE but your sample shows otherwise (two `Tim`s)

Comment: @Brendan's answer will not raise error (I think) but it's not predictable which Tim will assign as father to children with father named Tim. This question results in paternity issues!

Comment: I added a fix for the `SELECT`, now it'll select the first entry.

Answer (score 4):

Join the table with itself using the parent name and then do the swap:

```
UPDATE table t1 LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t2.Name = t1.Parent
SET t1.Parent = t2.Id
```

**UPDATE:** I see I managed to write almost the exact same statement as niktrs. Although I've assumed that you want to swap the values instead of using a new column.

Comment: I think it's better to create a new column, and then drop the old one, since old type is varchar and new type is integer

Comment: +1 and your answer is correct. niktrs was faster but he did some mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

Create a column `ParentId`

Then join the table with itself

```
UPDATE table t1 JOIN table t2 ON t1.parent = t2.name
SET t1.ParentId = t2.Id
```

Comment: It have to be `t2.parentId = t1.Id` and there is no `ParentId`column.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with the code. Also i say that he has first to create a ParentId column to hold the information.

Comment: You're writing child IDs to the parentId column.

Comment: I match each name with the parents name and then i update the name's parent id with the id of the parent.

Comment: My mind is a little tired, fatal, couldn't see my mistake. Thanks for insisting!

Comment: Hey, it's friday..so what? :-)